# In which countries are iPhone health records available?

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app, health-kit

I just found what I was looking for. [Health records are available on an iPhone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7IBlOh5DPE). But it seems I cannot directly input the data, it must be done by a medical institution.

In which countries are iPhone health records available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, apple lists three countries for [health records on iOS](https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#health-health-records).

> - Canada
> - United Kingdom
> - United States

https://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/

Comment: Since I'm not on one of these countries, is there any other app/website which does similar service? Having my lab results on paper looks medieval.

Comment: I drop scans in notes, but I don’t have many records online yet @KcFnMi -  You could ask a full question - we have help on asking for software recommendations - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation

Comment: Even then at least in UK only a very few (2?) health authorities seem to have this